# Does anyone know about this blur/erode effect?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes, effects

I wonder how this effect can be recreated inside the Blender shader.

Animation:

[image]

This is the image:

[image]

Comment: The effect looks like *Erode* filter node + *Blur* filter node (of the *Compositor*). For the animation, I guess you need to do this for each frame with the filtered result of the previous frame (create a loop/increased number of applications of the filter for each frame. I have no idea how to do this).

Comment: oh, wait, of course, you can use the frame number. There is a *Scene Time* node that provides this information. But the other nodes have no input slot for the required... bummer. After all, you must use a driver. (example https://imgur.com/a/uLLIPIB)

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic, see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks.

Comment: Can we recreate this using OSL, how?

Comment: This effect looks like Gimp's Median Blur with Percentile set to small value and some Gaussian Blur on top of it. You have to work on an Image Texture to get this effect. How exactly do you plan to use it?